Storing a parsed JSON file into a struct array using a function?
I'm trying to build a client/server application that, on the client side, establishes a TCP connection and sends a parsed JSON file through a char buffer. But first, I need to parse the JSON file, which I am doing using the Jansson library and storing into an array of structs. This is my struct:
#define DEFAULT_LENGTH 22

typedef struct {
    char key[DEFAULT_LENGTH];
    char value[DEFAULT_LENGTH];
} jsonLine;

For modularity/compartmentalization, I wish to dynamically allocate the array in main, and pass its address to a function, which will then build it inside there. However, it's not working. The issue isn't necessarily with the JSON library, since I tried the code in main and it worked perfectly.
The issue is more with passing the array and building it. This is my code:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    //parse given json file into struct
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("missing JSON file in cmd line arg!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    jsonLine *config = (jsonLine*) malloc(11 * sizeof(DEFAULT_LENGTH)*2);
    parseconfig(&config, argv);

And this is the parseconfig(): (I won't show the whole thing, just what I think is delivering segmentation fault error)
void parseconfig (jsonLine **arr, char *input[]) {

   //storing values in struct array
    strcpy((**arr).key,"server_ip_addr");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "server_ip_addr")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"UDP_src_port");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "UDP_src_port")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"UDP_dest_port");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "UDP_dest_port")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"TCP_dest_port_headSYN");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "TCP_dest_port_headSYN")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"TCP_dest_port_tailSYN");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "TCP_dest_port_tailSYN")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"TCP_port_preProb");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "TCP_port_preProb")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"TCP_port_postProb");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "TCP_port_postProb")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"UDP_packet_size");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "UDP_packet_size")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"inter_time");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "inter_time")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"UDP_train_size");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "UDP_train_size")));
    (*arr)++;
    strcpy((**arr).key,"UDP_TTL");
    strcpy((**arr).value,json_string_value(json_object_get(root, "UDP_TTL")));
    json_decref(root);

To be honest, I have no idea what the problem is, and might just transfer the code to the main function for simplicity.

jsonLine *config = (jsonLine*) malloc(11 * sizeof(DEFAULT_LENGTH)*2);
parseconfig(&config, argv);

This is allocating memory for 11 * sizeof(typeof(22)) * 2. The problem is that you are allocating memory for 2x times 11 typeof(22) instead of 11 jsonLines. The correct calculation is:
/* Or use const size_t before C24. */
constexpr auto config_count = 11;

/* sizeof *config eases maintainence. If you change the type of config,
 * you wouldn't need to change the type for sizeof too. */
jsonLine *config = malloc(config_count * sizeof *config); 

Also note that since ISO C89, or around 35 years, malloc() and family have returned a generic void * that is implicitly converted to and from any other pointer type. As such, the result of malloc() need not be casted and only serves to clutter the codebase. This is different for C++, where there is no implicit conversion from a void * to any other pointer type.

Furthermore:
strcpy((**arr).key,"server_ip_addr");

can be written as:
strcpy((*arr)->key,"server_ip_addr");

See: Arrow operator (->) usage in C Though, you did not require a pointer to a pointer here, but the whole code hasn't been posted, so this is a mere observation at best.
And instead of repeating the call to strcpy() 22 times, use an array and a loop:
/* Or use #define before C24. */
constexpr auto num_entries = 11; /*  Or get this value with sizeof json_keys / sizeof keys_count[0]. */

static const char *const json_keys[keys_count] = {
    "server_ip_addr",
    "UDP_src_port",
    "UDP_dest_port",
    "TCP_dest_port_headSYN",
    "TCP_dest_port_tailSYN",
    "TCP_port_preProb",
    "TCP_port_postProb",
    "UDP_packet_size",
    "inter_time",
    "UDP_train_size",
    "UDP_TTL"
};

for (size_t i = 0; i < keys_count; ++i) {
    strcpy((*arr)->key, json_keys[i]);
    strcpy((*arr)->value, json_string_value(json_object_get(root, json_keys[i])));
    (*arr)++;
}

And error messages go to stderr, not stdout.
